# How to snap Frostina using the Yo-Kai Cam?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

I'm trying to get Frostina on the Yo-kai Cam.

I've tried various angles of the image below with no success. I did get a few different yo-kai, but not Frostina, sadly.

Is there any reliable way to snap Frostina? If not, how does the yo-kai cam determine what yokai to show? There seems to be certain Yo-kai that show up over and over again.

[image: The image I've been trying with]

Answer (score 1):

To partially answer your question:

Yo-Kai are supposed to show what type of Yo-Kai that person would convey in the real world - how the game chooses what Yo-Kai is chosen is probably only known to the developers.

If the game has decided that the person you chose doesn't portray Frostina's personality, than a new person's photo should be used.